# Committed folder shows orange in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Am debugging a site, and I just noticed that the reason why the site is broken is because a folder is empty in the repository(GitLab), consequently the server.

Locally, I navigate to the folder and see its contents, but when I go to the Gitlab repo, the folder looks orange like in the image below, and I am not able to open it:

[image]

If I rename the folder, it shows like others, once I give the name that was previously committed, it shows in orange with the numbers next to it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: @Brian61354270 which command do I run to solve this issue?